# Karate tests in other folder than src/test

Tags: cucumber, karate, cucumberjs

I want to move Karate tests from src/test to a new folder src/it because it makes sense to me to have integration tests separated from unit tests.

Is that possible?

I tried to put java classes in src/it/java and features in src/it/resources and Karate tests run, but without test cases.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was solved using a Maven plugin to add src/it/java as test sources and src/it/resources as test resources:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/it/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-resource</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```