# How to Configure Karate Tests in Gradle with a Custom Project Structure

Tags: build.gradle, karate

I'm trying to set up Karate tests in a Gradle project, but my project has a custom directory structure, and I'm having trouble configuring the source sets correctly. Here's my project structure:

my_project/
└── src/
└── systemTest/
└── java/
└── resources/

I'm not using the standard **src/main** directory for the main application code, and I don't have a **src/test** directory either. I need to configure Karate tests in this structure, but the usual Gradle scripts for Karate don't seem to apply.

Can someone provide guidance on how to configure Karate tests in this custom directory structure using Gradle? I'd like to create separate source sets for different types of tests (e.g., integration tests, system tests), specify the source directories, and set up dependencies correctly.

Any help or example Gradle configurations specific to Karate in such a project structure would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried couple of options suggested through online search but none of them are working.

> Also, I am not sure if this existing solution posted in stack overflow works for maven - [Karate tests in other folder than src/test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874738/karate-tests-in-other-folder-than-src-test) ??. We need similar stuff for gradle.

following is the complete content of my build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:1.4.1"
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/systemTest/java')
            exclude '**/*.java'
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:1.4.1'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "karate.options", System.properties.getProperty("karate.options")
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // mavenLocal()
}

task karateDebug(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.intuit.karate.cli.Main'
}
```

Comment: I asked around and no-one seems to know. you should seriously consider sticking to a "standard" directory structure

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @peter-thomas for your quick updates!!!

I managed to resolve this and here is the build.gradle file content which works for custom folder structure such as /src/systemTest/java.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation "com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:1.4.1"
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/systemTest/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/systemTest/java'
            exclude '**/*.java'
        }
    }
}

task runSystemTests(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "karate.options", System.properties.getProperty("karate.options")
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**